# Prevent CEDET semantic from parsing certain file types

Tags: c, emacs, cedet

I have to work with a C/C++ build environment that drops intermediate files all over the place:

- `.i` files containing the output of the C-preprocessor (roughly raw C)
- `.s` files containing the input of the C-assembler

CEDET (I assume the semantic analyzer) eventually finds these files and attempts to index them.  This results in jumping to `.i` files containing raw C for definitions and generally slowing down parsing and loading of the .semanticdb.

I never open these files in emacs, so they must be being loaded by the background analyser.

Is it possible to prevent the analyser from loading these files?  I can't find any configuration options that define the file-types that are parsed by the background analyser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never need C mode for these files, here's a quick fix:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.i\\'" . fundamental-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.s\\'" . fundamental-mode))
```

Comment: So the semantic-analyzer simply loads files it "knows about" because of the `mode-alist`?   That's cunning, but frustrating, as it is a global list.  That said the workaround is probably OK for me.

Comment: No, semantic starts because "*.i" file opens in `c-mode` by default.
And you've configured to parse all `c-mode` buffers.
Having "*.i" start in fundamental mode is therefore a work-around.

Comment: Hmm,... so maybe that's not it - I've never opened these files in emacs to trigger such parsing (except accidentally when using semantic to find a symbol has taken me there, because the analyser has already found and indexed them).

Comment: Semantic opens them if they are includes of the files that you have
opened.

Comment: Nope, none of these are includes - as I said they are byproducts of the compile environment (cf `gcc -save-temps`), and thus none of them are referenced in source-code - which references the real files (.c or .h).  Our real assembler files are `.S`, and `.i` is not used at all.  Perhaps semantic is opening them as candidates for the for body files when it sees the corresponding `#include x.h`.

Comment: I followed the idea above using `(delete '("\\.i\\'" . c-mode) auto-mode-alist)`, etc,.. instead, and have been running for a day without these files being sucked in by semantic.  I'll try your specific version (setting `fundamenal-mode`) before accepting your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer from abo-abo gave me the clues I needed. The `grep` implementation (used by EDE) of `semantic-symref-perform-search` uses `auto-mode-alist` to find matching files for a given semantic mode (based on the current buffer's mode - eg `c-mode) when trying to resolve symbols.

The final fix I used is to specifically eliminate the default entries in the `auto-mode-alist` using:

`(delete '("\\.i\\'" . c-mode) auto-mode-alist)
(delete '("\\.ii\\'" . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist)`

Adding `fundamental-mode` entries as suggested by abo-abo seems to work also, however I was concerned that since the `c-mode` entries were still in the list a change in implementation could result in them being reactivated.